# Error fetching data from website

Tags: objective-c, macos, web-scraping, request

Hi so I wanted to retrieve data from this website: http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now for an app that I was making, but when I make the request with the following code, I always get null:

```
NSURL * timeAPI = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now"];

NSURLRequest * urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:timeAPI];

__block NSData * responseData;

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    if(connectionError)
    {
        NSLog(@"error fetching data");
    }
    else{
        responseData = [[NSData alloc]initWithData:data];
    }
}];

NSError* error = nil;
NSLog(@"%@, erorr:", responseData);
```

Can anyone figure out the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request takes time and at your log statement the data has not arrived yet. Put a log of responseData in the else clause, that is when the data is available and you will see it.

You do not need (or want) the the __block declaration.
`[[NSData alloc]initWithData:data]` is unnecessary, just use `initWithData:data`.

Example code:

```
NSURL * timeAPI = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now"];
NSURLRequest * urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:timeAPI];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    if(connectionError) {
        NSLog(@"error fetching data: %@", connectionError);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"data: %@", data);

        NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"dataString: %@", dataString);

        // Do something with the data
    }
}];
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll make the change; Also, how do I get around using the block declaration? If I don't use it then it says I'm missing the block identifier.

Comment: In the completion block save the data to a property or put it in a notification. Using self to set a property is fine since the block is not references by self.